# Google Basemap doesn't align with data after export

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openlayers, google

Help!

I put together a map in QGIS and everything looks good in the composer view, however when I export to PDF, the projection/data seems to have shifted from the Google Open Layers basemap.

I followed the instructions for adding the Google basemap from here:
https://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/basemap.php

Part of this guide had me change the project CRS to WGS 84 Pseudo Mercator.

Since I was having trouble, I attempted to fix the issue by right-clicking on each layer and changing the CRS to WGS 84 Pseudo Mercator as well. This made it worse.
[image]
The attached image shows what my PDF looks like at this point.

Comment: This could be intentional, Google doesn't like you printing its layers. The Google imagery disappears when you try to export. Can you export the Google layers by selection or clip to a subset shapefile?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelStimson - I just changed the basemap and the day has been saved.

Comment: Uninstall openlayers asap - it's a buggy plugin, guaranteed to make your life a misery. Use QuickMapServices instead.